# Riesz mapping is an isomorphism between spaces over R?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If I have a Hilbert space $H$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$, Riesz mapping existence implies that $H$ is isomorphic to $H^*$? I mean, Riesz map is an isomorphism between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $x \in H$ we have $f_x:H \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f_x(y)= \langle y, x \rangle$ and this does give an isometric isomorphism between $H$ and $H^{*}$. However if you replace the scalar filed by $\mathbb C$ then $x \to f_x$ is  not a linear map!